# How can I check if a list of folders exist in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find a matching list of folders on my  C:/ drive and then execute some code but its not working as expected.

I can do it fine with a single folder but not sure how to get it working with a list of folders that I want to find.

**My code**

```
Dir.glob("C:/*")

directory_list = Array.new

directory_list << "FolderA"
directory_list << "FolderB"

    if Dir.exists?(directory_list)

        puts "Does exist"

    else

        puts "Does not Exist"
    end
```

**The following solution provided a proof of concept for me**

```
 dirs = ["FolderA", "FolderB"] 
 reg = Regexp.union dirs exists, 
 rest = Dir.glob("{B,C,D}:/*").partition{ |path| path =~ reg } 
 puts exists
```

With thanks to Kyle in the chat room.

Comment: Do you want this to search recursively through your C drive for these folders?

Comment: Recursively please if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, the directories are prepended with the drive so you need to:

```
"C:/FolderB" =~ /FolderB|FolderA/
```

The code:

```
dirs = ["FolderA", "Folderb"] 
reg = Regexp.union dirs 
exists, rest = Dir.glob("C:/*").partition{ |path| path =~ reg }
# now you have two arrays, one of directories that exist and the rest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c_drive = Dir.glob("**/")
%w(FolderA, FolderB).each do |dir|
  if c_drive.include?(dir)
    puts "#{dir} exists"
  else
    puts "#{dir} does not exist"
  end
end
```

Comment: This does not seem to work - I have added FolderB to C:/ but the code returns that it does not exist.

Comment: @Ninja2k try fiddling with the Dir.glob line. I'm not sure how this would work on a Windows box, maybe Dir.glob("C:/**/")

Comment: We got something to work above, I need to get my head around the code so as to integrate it with the rest of my program.